# Pyramid of doom

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, q

I have this routing code to a node.js express application and I'm trying to use `q` to use promises instead of getting into "callback hell". I'm including a "service layer" above, and need to make two calls, and return a json structure with data from both functions.

```
var express = require('express');
var q = require('q');
var service = require('./../model/service');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/trips', function(req, res, next) {
    service.getAllTrips(function(err, trips) {
        if (err) throw err;
        service.getPeopleForTrips(function(err, people) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var json = {
                trips: trips,
                people: people
            };
            return res.json(json);
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I've tried to separate both service calls into what the `q` example shows [here](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/), but still can't get it to work or how to structure this example. Thanks for the help in advance.

This is what I've tried:

```
q.fcall(service.getAllTrips)
    .then(service.getPeopleForTrips)
    .then(function (data1, data2) {
        console.log(data1);
        console.log(data2);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
    .done();
```

Comment: Paste your code so  we can see what your trying to do

Comment: @tmcgoo Edited with what I've tried with `q`.

Comment: @tmcgoo Instead `fcall` make `nfcall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`q.nfcall()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node) for node-style functions which takes callback in `cb(err, result)` format. The sequential form:

```
var trips;
q.nfcall(service.getAllTrips)
.then(function(data){
    trips= data
    return q.nfcall(service.getPeopleForTrips)
})
.then(function (people) {
    console.log(trips, people);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.done();
```

Using `q.all` you can run the array of promises in parallel and then using [`q.spread`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination) to spread the returned array as arguments of fulfillment handler:

```
q.all([
    q.nfcall(service.getAllTrips),
    q.nfcall(service.getPeopleForTrips)
]).spread(function(trips, people){
    console.log(trips, people);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.done();
```